# UnicodeDecodeError when I read a large file using pd.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, unicode

```
train = pd.read_csv('./train_vec.csv', header=None,sep=',',names=['label', 'vec', 'vec_with_sims'])
```

Got the error below :

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xaf in position
>   3: invalid start byte

At first I thought it was a problem with the encoding format, but when I tried to read only part of the dataset(for example,only read 10000 rows),

```
train = pd.read_csv('./train_vec.csv',nrows=10000,header=None,sep=',',names=['label', 'vec', 'vec_with_sims'])
```

the error disappeared!

Is it because the training set is too big (2.4G)? My system configuration:
Ubuntu16.04, GTX1070, 16G memory
i think it is enough!
What's even more strange is that every time the computer restarts, the training set can be loaded normally, but after a while, trying to load the training set again will get the same error.

Comment: Have you tried adding `encoding='latin-1'` ?

Comment: Please add the code-blocks around your code, and also mark the output separately from the normal text. It improves the readability of the code and the question.

Comment: The data is not UTF-8, and there wasn't a non-ASCII character in the first 10,000 rows.  Use the correct encoding.  `latin1` will work because it can't fail, but it may not be the correct encoding.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is very useful.
I checked the data carefully and found that the file format of the training set has changed to latin1.
I'm sure the file was previously in utf-8 format, but I reinstalled the system a few days ago, moved the file to the mobile hard drive, and then moved back to my Ubuntu, would this result in a change in the file encoding format? But my test set file format has not changed, only this train_vec.csv file has become latin1.@Erfan@Mark Tolonen

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add **encoding='unicode_escape'**

For example:

**train = pd.read_csv(r'./train_vec.csv', header=None,sep=',',names=['label', 'vec', 'vec_with_sims'],encoding='unicode_escape')**